# .htaccess rewrite rule causes wrong links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to make pretty URLs for my website like there:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

It works, root/profile/123 opens root/profile.php?id=123, but the folder paths are now broken:

root/profile.php?id=123 references for example root/css/style.css

but root/profile/123 wants to reference root/profile/css/style.css, which doesn't exist.

I want to have it both ways working: root/profile.php?id=123 and root/profile/123

How can i fix the link problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an alias for anything that would be accessed via `/root/profile/` with `Alias`:

```
Alias /root/profile /real/path/root
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

If you are limited to a `.htaccess` file you can add another rewrite rule before the one you already have:

```
RewriteRule ^root/profile/(.*)$ /profile/$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)*$ /profile.php?id=$1
```

As the first rule would redirect any access to files at root/profile to profile, which is in turn evaluated by the second rewriterule, this would lead to an infinite loop. The flag `[L]`, which stands for "last" tells the rewriteengine to stop further processing, if it encounters a path starting with "root/profile".

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to test at the moment. What is the error? - Added a backslash before the `.css` in the regex.

Comment: profile.php and .htaccess are in the same directory - Error 500 -

**AliasMatch ^profile(.*) ./$1**

Comment: I'd like to reference all files correct (links, images, css, javascript, etc)

Comment: In this case, it should be even simpler, with `alias`; see update.

Comment: i tried **Alias ./profile ./** but the error 500 is still there. maybe i have to activate the alias anywhere in apache? or does it not work with relative paths?

Comment: I found the following: The "Alias" directive is not allowed in .htaccess files. According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias, "Alias" is only allowed in "server config, virtual host". That's why you get a 500 error when you set it in the .htaccess context.

Comment: And you don't have access to your server config?

Comment: Sure, but is there no other way? For example, wordpress does not change the server config but has this pretty links.